# How to change all values in 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, temperature

I'm a student in a Java Programming class and my problem deals with converting all the temperatures in the 2d array from Fahrenheit to Celsius. The array has all the temperatures for each hour of the day for a month. The instructor afterwards gave us a print statement to see if the array converted and mine didn't. The getTemperature method just points out a specific temperature in the array and it should have been converted to celsius when used in the print statement. I tried doing this.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // [day][hour]
    double[][] temps = {
        {30.9, 30.9, 30.9, 33.1, 36.0, 36.0, 37.4, 39.0, 43.0, 48.2, 51.1, 55.9, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 57.0, 54.0, 53.1, 55.0, 57.0, 59.0, 57.9, 57.0},
        {57.0, 59.0, 59.0, 60.1, 61.0, 63.0, 63.0, 63.0, 63.0, 62.1, 61.0, 61.0, 60.1, 59.0, 57.9, 57.0, 55.4, 52.0, 48.9, 46.0, 44.1, 42.1, 39.0, 36.0},
        {36.0, 34.0, 32.0, 30.9, 28.9, 28.0, 26.1, 30.0, 33.8, 35.1, 37.9, 41.0, 43.0, 44.6, 43.0, 43.0, 41.0, 39.0, 36.0, 34.0, 32.0, 32.0, 28.9, 28.9},
        {30.0, 28.9, 26.6, 27.0, 28.0, 28.0, 30.9, 41.0, 48.9, 51.1, 52.0, 53.1, 54.0, 55.0, 55.0, 54.0, 53.1, 51.1, 51.1, 50.0, 48.9, 50.0, 51.8, 51.8},
        {51.1, 48.9, 48.9, 46.9, 46.0, 46.0, 45.0, 45.0, 46.0, 46.0, 46.9, 48.9, 53.1, 55.0, 55.0, 54.0, 52.0, 46.9, 44.1, 41.0, 37.9, 36.0, 33.1, 32.0},
        {30.0, 28.0, 27.0, 25.0, 23.0, 21.9, 24.1, 26.1, 28.0, 30.9, 34.0, 37.0, 39.2, 42.1, 43.0, 43.0, 43.0, 39.9, 39.0, 39.0, 37.9, 37.9, 37.0, 35.1},
        {32.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.1, 33.1, 32.0, 32.0, 33.1, 42.1, 46.9, 52.0, 55.0, 57.0, 59.0, 57.9, 57.0, 53.1, 50.0, 48.9, 48.9, 48.9, 48.0, 48.9, 48.9},
        {48.0, 48.9, 48.9, 48.2, 48.9, 50.0, 48.9, 51.1, 55.9, 60.8, 64.0, 66.9, 69.1, 69.1, 66.9, 68.0, 64.9, 60.1, 57.0, 55.9, 57.0, 55.9, 55.0, 55.9},
        {55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.6, 53.1, 51.1, 51.1, 51.1, 57.9, 61.0, 66.9, 69.1, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 66.9, 64.0, 60.1, 57.9, 55.9, 57.0, 55.0, 54.0, 52.0},
        {50.0, 52.0, 52.0, 50.0, 48.9, 46.0, 44.1, 43.0, 41.0, 41.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.9, 39.9, 39.0, 39.9, 39.0, 37.9, 37.9, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.2},
        {37.9, 37.9, 37.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 37.0, 37.0, 37.9, 39.0, 41.0, 43.0, 46.9, 48.2, 48.9, 44.1, 39.9, 37.0, 36.0, 36.0, 34.0, 33.1},
        {32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 33.8, 34.0, 33.1, 33.1, 42.1, 52.0, 57.0, 61.0, 63.0, 64.0, 64.9, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 55.9, 46.9, 44.1, 42.8, 39.0, 37.0, 34.0},
        {33.1, 30.9, 30.0, 28.9, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.9, 30.9, 30.9, 33.1, 36.0, 36.0, 37.0, 39.0, 39.2, 37.9, 35.1, 30.0, 30.9, 28.9, 25.0, 24.1, 24.8},
        {24.1, 23.0, 23.0, 21.9, 23.0, 21.0, 23.0, 26.1, 37.0, 43.0, 46.9, 50.0, 51.1, 51.1, 51.1, 52.0, 51.1, 48.9, 48.0, 48.9, 50.0, 51.1, 51.1, 51.1},
        {50.0, 39.0, 33.1, 30.2, 27.0, 25.0, 23.0, 23.0, 24.1, 26.1, 27.0, 28.9, 30.9, 33.1, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 30.9, 30.0, 28.0, 26.1, 26.1, 24.1, 23.0},
        {23.0, 23.0, 23.0, 24.1, 25.0, 24.1, 23.0, 24.1, 26.1, 27.0, 28.9, 32.0, 34.0, 33.1, 33.1, 33.1, 32.0, 33.1, 37.0, 39.0, 42.1, 44.6, 48.2, 48.2},
        {39.9, 36.0, 36.0, 60.8, 52.0, 35.1, 36.0, 33.1, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 33.1, 32.0, 32.0, 30.9, 30.9, 30.9, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 28.9},
        {28.9, 27.0, 27.0, 27.0, 27.0, 28.0, 27.0, 28.9, 33.1, 36.0, 39.0, 42.1, 44.1, 46.9, 48.0, 46.9, 45.0, 43.0, 41.0, 42.1, 39.0, 37.0, 36.0, 32.0},
        {30.9, 30.0, 28.0, 26.1, 24.1, 23.0, 21.0, 21.9, 23.0, 24.1, 25.0, 26.6, 28.0, 28.9, 30.0, 28.9, 28.0, 26.1, 25.0, 21.9, 19.9, 21.0, 19.0, 19.0},
        {19.0, 18.0, 17.1, 15.8, 15.1, 14.0, 12.9, 14.0, 17.1, 19.9, 23.0, 26.1, 28.0, 30.0, 30.9, 32.0, 30.9, 28.0, 25.0, 21.9, 21.9, 21.9, 21.0, 19.9},
        {19.9, 19.9, 21.0, 19.9, 19.9, 19.9, 21.9, 27.0, 37.0, 45.0, 48.0, 50.0, 53.1, 55.9, 57.9, 57.0, 57.0, 55.0, 53.1, 54.0, 55.9, 55.0, 55.4, 55.9},
        {55.9, 55.9, 55.9, 55.4, 55.9, 55.0, 48.9, 48.0, 59.0, 61.0, 64.0, 64.9, 66.9, 66.0, 66.9, 66.0, 64.9, 63.0, 62.1, 59.0, 57.0, 57.9, 57.0, 55.9},
        {55.0, 55.9, 55.0, 55.4, 55.0, 54.0, 57.2, 55.9, 57.0, 55.9, 46.9, 46.0, 44.1, 42.8, 41.0, 39.9, 39.0, 37.9, 37.0, 37.0, 35.1, 33.1, 32.0, 30.9},
        {30.9, 30.9, 30.9, 30.0, 30.0, 28.9, 28.0, 26.1, 27.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.9, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.9, 30.9, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0},
        {30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.2, 30.0, 30.0, 30.9, 30.9, 33.8, 33.1, 34.0, 36.0, 37.9, 39.9, 39.2, 39.0, 39.0, 37.9, 37.9, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 35.1},
        {35.1, 36.0, 37.9, 37.0, 37.9, 39.2, 37.0, 35.1, 35.1, 36.0, 37.9, 37.4, 39.0, 39.0, 39.2, 39.0, 39.0, 37.9, 37.9, 37.0, 37.0, 37.0, 37.0, 36.0},
        {36.0, 35.1, 34.0, 34.0, 33.1, 33.8, 32.0, 32.0, 37.4, 39.9, 45.0, 46.0, 48.0, 48.9, 50.0, 51.1, 46.9, 45.0, 41.0, 37.9, 39.0, 37.0, 36.0, 37.0},
        {35.1, 33.1, 32.0, 30.9, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 33.1, 37.0, 41.0, 45.0, 46.9, 48.9, 50.0, 46.9, 45.0, 43.0, 42.1, 39.9, 39.9, 39.0, 37.9, 37.9}
    };
    convertToCelsius(temps);
    System.out.println("Day 7 - Hour 5: " + getTemperature(temps, 7, 5)); // Should be 10.0 (starting at 0)
}
    public static double getTemperature (double[][] temps, int day, int hour) {
    double temp = 0;
    double temp2 = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < temps.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < temps[row].length; col++) {
            temp = row;
            temp2 = col;
        }
    }
    return temp + temp2;
}

public static double c2f (double c) {
    double temp = (c * 9.0/5) + 32.0;
    return temp;
}

public static void convertToCelsius(double[][] temps) {
    for (int row = 0; row < temps.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < temps[row].length; col++) {
            temps[row][col] = c2f(temps[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `getTemperature` use `day` and `hour`?

Comment: The conversion works. Your entire double array is converted correctly. The mistake is that the method `getTemperature` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Nvm what I said, I somehow mixed in arrays with other primitives. Quick tip: debug by printing. Remember that your program only does what you tell it to do.

Comment: @pbabcdefp "getTemperature makes no sense at all" That's what I was trying to point out with my question to the op. I like to try and invoke thought and not just point out exactly what is wrong. Hoping op went something like "oh, right. Why am I passing those in, and what should I be doing with them?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missunderstood the meaning of "day 7 - hour 5" as a subtraction of two numbers, but imho just means to get the temperature on day 7 at hour 5. so the getTemperature method should look something like this

```
//Assumes that day and hour counting start at 0
    public static double getTemperature (double[][] temps, int day, int hour) {
        return temps[day][hour];
    }

//Assumes that day and hour counting start at 1
    public static double getTemperature (double[][] temps, int day, int hour) {
        return temps[day-1][hour-1];
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will return wrong results or cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

`getTemperature(temps, 1, 1)` will NOT return Day 1 - Hour 1 but Day 2 - Hour 2

Comment: it depends on how what kind of convention you use for your day counting. but yes, I agree if you that it I should have added a comment -> edited accordingly.

Comment: That is irrelevant, even though `x` is clearly hours and `y` is days. Array accesing is zero based. If you want Day1 - Hour 1 you have to `return temps[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you expect the temperature of Day 7 - Hour 5 to be 10. The temperature in celcious is 33.1 which should convert to 91.58 fahrenheit.

Your codes converts the temperatures correctly. Its just your `getTemperature (double[][] temps, int day, int hour)` that makes no sense.

Change that method to

```
public static double getTemperature (double[][] temps, int day, int hour){
    return temps[day-1][hour-1];
}
```

Now calling this :
`System.out.println("Day 7 - Hour 5: " + getTemperature(temps, 7, 5));` returns `91.58`